# Adjusted Rand Index for Affinity Propagation Clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, evaluation

I want to calculate Adjusted Rand Index for Affinity Propagation. I have a dataset containing sentences like this:

```
Youtube
Facebook
Whatsapp
Open Youtube
```

My Affinity Propagation code is as follows:

```
import nltk, string 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text
import TfidfVectorizer from sklearn.cluster
import AffinityPropagation
import pandas as pd

punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation) stemmer = nltk.stem.snowball.SpanishStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize)

def get_clusters(sentences):
    tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
    similarity_matrix = (tf_idf_matrix * tf_idf_matrix.T).A
    affinity_propagation = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
    affinity_propagation.fit(similarity_matrix)

    labels = affinity_propagation.labels_
    global cluster_centers
    cluster_centers = affinity_propagation.cluster_centers_indices_


    tagged_sentences = zip(sentences, labels)
    clusters = {}

    for sentence, cluster_id in tagged_sentences:
        clusters.setdefault(sentences[cluster_centers[cluster_id]], []).append(sentence)
        #print(len(sentence))

    return clusters

#csv file filename = "/home/ubuntu/data/local_queries.csv" df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)

sentences = df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()

clusters = get_clusters(sentences) print() for cluster in clusters:
    print(cluster, ':')
    for element in clusters[cluster]:
        print('  - ', element)
```

For ARI we need actual labels and predicted labels. I don't have actual labels as I just have sentences in my dataset. Can anyone please explain how should I calculate ARI in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARI is an *external* evaluation measure.

It can *only* be used to compare two results. Usually you compare a clustering to a known class labeling to test that the implementation is working.

**You *cannot* compute ARI if you only have one result and no "true" labels.**

In such cases, you can only use *internal* evaluation measures, with all their drawbacks.